# How to manage separate node.js microservices using npm 'concurrently'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a React App, with a Node.js backend. On the server I'm forwarding the request to other servers. 
The structure looks like this:

MyApp (folder)

```
-client(react)

-server(node.js)
```

MicroServers (folder)

```
-micro-server1(node.js)

-micro-server2(node.js)
```

-more

How do I use concurrently to start all the micro-servers at the same time?
Where do I install it? from where do I run it?

The instructions are:
In package.json, escape quotes:

"start": "concurrently \"command1 arg\" \"command2 arg\""

In the package.json of which of the above (server? one of the microservices, create another one?)? ()

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wouldn't phrase this as using npm concurrently. Instead, I'd phrase it something like "How to manage separate node.js microservices". That might better represent that problem you're having.

As for that, you can probably have your server serve up the react assets which takes care of `MyApp`. As for the microservices/microservers, are those going to be on the same machine? Different machines?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the note. I've added that to the title. They are going to run on the same machine, at least for now